# std::variant store multiple string types and tell them apart

Tags: c++, std, c++17, variant

In C++17, I'm implementing a toy vm. I'm using a std::variant() as the elements of the VM's stack. I need to push strings onto the stack which represent different kinds of operands, namely:

- a variable name
- an identifier
- a quoted string

All 3 types of operands can be of type std::string_view. The variant is defined like so:

```
std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string_view>;
```

In order to discriminate about the actual type of string view, is the correct way to do something like this?

```
enum StringKind { Symbol, String, Var };
using Stringy = std::tuple<StringKind, std::string_view>; // SV can be symbol, var, string
std::variant<bool, int, double, Stringy>;
```

Or is it possible to encode the string kind right at the variant. One of the benefits of doing it at the variant level is that the type can be had by calling std::variant::index(). Otherwise, I have to check for .index() == 3, std::get<3>(var), and then inspect the type to see if its string, symbol, or var.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and I like it:

```
enum StackStringType {};
enum StackSymbolType {}
enum StackVarType {};

using StackString = std::tuple<StackStringType, std::string_view>;
using StackSymbol = std::tuple<StackSymbolType, std::string_view>;
using StackVar    = std::tuple<StackVarType, std::string_view>;

using StackType = std::variant<bool, StackString, StackSymbol, StackVar>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to create a templated class to "tag" the various enum types. This avoids the need to have a "using" statement for each enum value so you repeat yourself less.

```
enum class StringKind { Symbol, String, Var };
template <StringKind T> struct TaggedString { std::string_view value; };
using StackType = std::variant<bool,
                               int,
                               double,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::Symbol>,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::String>,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::Var>>;
```

Also, you mentioned using `std::variant::index()` to get the type contained in the variant. Another way to do this is to use `std::visit()` in the following way to be a bit more type safe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>

template<typename T> struct always_false : std::false_type { };
enum class StringKind { Symbol, String, Var };
template <StringKind T> struct TaggedString { std::string_view value; };
using StackType = std::variant<bool,
                               int,
                               double,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::Symbol>,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::String>,
                               TaggedString<StringKind::Var>>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const StackType& st) {
    std::visit([&stream](auto&& var) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(var)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>) {
            stream << "Bool(" << var << ")";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
            stream << "Int(" << var << ")";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
            stream << "Double(" << var << ")";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, TaggedString<StringKind::Symbol>>) {
            stream << "Symbol(" << var.value << ")";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, TaggedString<StringKind::String>>) {
            stream << "String(" << var.value << ")";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, TaggedString<StringKind::Var>>) {
            stream << "Var(" << var.value << ")";
        } else {
            static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
        }
    }, st);
    return stream;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    StackType t_bool   = true;
    StackType t_int    = 3;
    StackType t_double = 3.0;
    StackType t_symbol = TaggedString<StringKind::Symbol>{"Foo"};
    StackType t_string = TaggedString<StringKind::String>{"Bar"};
    StackType t_var    = TaggedString<StringKind::Var>{"Baz"};
    std::cout << t_bool   << std::endl
              << t_int    << std::endl
              << t_double << std::endl
              << t_symbol << std::endl
              << t_string << std::endl
              << t_var    << std::endl;
}
```

This program outputs:

```
Bool(1)
Int(3)
Double(3)
Symbol(Foo)
String(Bar)
Var(Baz)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
struct StackString : std::string_view {};
struct StackSymbol : std::string_view {};
struct StackVar : std::string_view {};

using StackType = std::variant<bool, int, double, StackString, StackSymbol, StackVar>;
```